# Only change permissions in an apk and republish on playstore

Tags: android, apk, decode, apktool

Recently Google has asked me to remove one permission (SEND_SMS) from my android app and republish it. The problem is that I got this prebuilt app from some company and now they are asking for extra amount for only changing this permission. During initial purchase also I had told them not to include but they kept it. Now I want to edit android menifest by removing the permission for SEND_SMS, rebuild and sign the app and publish.Please note that I don't have the source code of the project, but my work I believe is only limited to android menifest. Is it even possible? if yes, How?

Thanks,
Abdul Wahid

Comment: The Simple answer is NO

Comment: If you don't have the source code, it's likely you don't have the legal right to modify/disassemble or modify the code.

Comment: Without having access to the source code, do you at least have access to the keystore they signed the APK (would they be willing at least to send that to you)? That's the strict minimum you need, and if you have it I can probably help you. Without it, nothing can be done.

Comment: @Pierre Dear, Yes, I have all the things( keystore file, password etc.) because I am the owner of the app. You can search for "Deshwali" app in playstore. So.. any hints?

Comment: Responded as a top-level solution for visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have the keystore, then you can use [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to decompile the APK, modify the manifest to increase the versionCode and remove that permission, then recompile it (still using apktool). Finally, re-sign the APK with apksigner using the keystore you have and publish the modified APK to Play Console.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I was skeptical if menifest file may appear in proper xml text after decompilation. Thanks for your answer. Let me try the steps mentioned by you and keep everybody posted. Thanks again.

Comment: It will probably not appear as XML, but as a list of properties in a text file (unless something has changed since last time I tried). You should be able to easily identify the properties that need to be changed since it's plain text, then you can save the modified file and recompile the APK.

Comment: Thanks pierre. It worked. I was able to rebuild the app. And all achieved. When I was uploading the apk to google play store, it was again asking to update target sdk version to 26. I did that also in menifesto and my notification system stopped working. Anyways, I have uploaded the new apk to play store by removing sms permission, so that solved my main issue. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting my answer as a solution then for others to easily find it. Regarding your notifications issue, I think that code would possibly need to change to adapt to the new SDK behaviour.

Comment: How does one go about signing the rebuilt app? @Pierre

Answer (score 4):

Even if you manage to manipulate the manifest, you still can not sign the `.apk`. You would need the keystore file to sign it for publishing.

Comment: Dears,
Apology for delayed reply.
Yes, I have keystore files and all the passwords etc., because I own the app. The app to modify is "Deshwali" ( You can search it on playstore.)
I believe it can be done by myself because it's not reverse enginnering, but just a configuration change.
Even I have seen this menifesto file in android studio already( in proper text format and located the SEND_SMS permission to which google has objected.
So any thought how can it be done?

Thanks,
Abdul Wahid